# Handle scrollview size in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Im making an horizontal `UICollectionView`, and inside `UICollectionViewCell` i have scrollview and inside the scrollview i have an imageView.

The issue I'm having is that when i zoom-in the imageView,scrollView is taking all the cell size, so its not fitting to the image size height and width.thus by scrolling up and down the image disappear from scrollview, i have no idea whats going wrong in my code.

My `ColectionViewCell` code:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var ImageV: UIImageView!
}
```

CollectionView code :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

  cell.scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
  cell.scrollView.delegate = self
  cell.ImageV.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])
  cell.ImageV.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

  cell.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
  cell.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4;
  cell.scrollView.contentSize = cell.ImageV.frame.size

  return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

  return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width , height: self.collectionView.frame.size.height - 100)

}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: Int(currentIndex), inSection: 0)

  if let cell1 = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {  
    let cell = cell1 as! CollectionViewCell
    let boundsSize = cell.scrollView.bounds.size
    var contentsFrame = cell.ImageV.frame

    if contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width{
      contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2
    }else{
      contentsFrame.origin.x = 0
    }

    if contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height {
      contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2
    }else{
      contentsFrame.origin.y = 0
    }
    return cell.ImageV    
  }      
   return UIView()     
 }


func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

  currentIndex = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
  oldcell = currentIndex - 1

  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: Int(oldcell), inSection: 0)
  if let cell1 = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    let cell = cell1 as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.scrollView.zoomScale = 0 
  }
}
```

**Image preview:**
https://i.imgur.com/Gr2p09A.gifv

**My project found here :** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B32ROW7V8Fj4RVZfVGliXzJseGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey Download the demo   and tell me its fine or not then after i will update my answer https://www.dropbox.com/s/i815mu0z4d0d76v/horizntal%203.zip?dl=0

Comment: Sure check it and Tell me :)

Comment: @RushangPrajapati , ScrollView scrolling property should be enabled, in your case its disabled thus i can zoom in out without scrolling to see the bounds of the image or the rest of it. any possible solution ?

Comment: Means you want to  Zoom in out without do Scoll View Property  Disabled?

Comment: Yes and to handle scrollview size to take image bounds only not the whole cell, as example open Photos app and zoom image in and scroll right and left in it.

Comment: Ok got it wait for my update :)

Comment: Have you watched this [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011-104/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well First lets start with `UIViewController` that is holding your `UICollectionView`:

Define a variable to hold the collection view layout:

```
var flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
```

You will have to override `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and this is going to handle the collectionView size.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height:view.frame.height)

}
```

Also you will need to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to handle the size of each new cell to set it to default size:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        if let currentCell = imageCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(desiredIndexPath) as? GalleryCell {
            currentCell.configureForNewImage()
        }
}
```

in `ViewDidLoad` setup the collectionView to be horizontal with flow layout:

```
    // Set up flow layout
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    // Set up collection view
    imageCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)

    imageCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageCollectionView.registerClass(GalleryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "GalleryCell")
    imageCollectionView.dataSource = self
    imageCollectionView.delegate = self
    imageCollectionView.pagingEnabled = true
    view.addSubview(imageCollectionView)

    imageCollectionView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1000.0, height: 1.0)
```

In your `UICollectionView` method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` load the image only without setting anything:

```
 cell.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])
```

Now lets move to `GalleryCell` class and to handle scrollView when zooming:

```
class GalleryCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var image:UIImage? {
        didSet {
            configureForNewImage()
        }
    }

     var scrollView: UIScrollView
     let imageView: UIImageView

   override init(frame: CGRect) {

        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: frame)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.addSubview(scrollView)
        contentView.addConstraints(scrollViewConstraints)

        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    internal func configureForNewImage() {
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.sizeToFit()

        setZoomScale()
        scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView)
    }

    public func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

    public func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
        let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size

        let verticalPadding = imageViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height ? (scrollViewSize.height - imageViewSize.height) / 2 : 0
        let horizontalPadding = imageViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width ? (scrollViewSize.width - imageViewSize.width) / 2 : 0

        if verticalPadding >= 0 {
            // Center the image on screen
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalPadding, left: horizontalPadding, bottom: verticalPadding, right: horizontalPadding)
        } else {
            // Limit the image panning to the screen bounds
            scrollView.contentSize = imageViewSize
        }


}
```

I've tested it with example and it should solve your issue with scrollview and @Spencevail explained mostly why it's being caused !

Comment: @Aaoli, i will check it out !

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `contentInset` on your scrollview. What's happening is The `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` is originally set to match the screen size with the image inside of that. As you zoom in on the scrollview, the contentSize expands proportionately, so those black areas above and below the photos when you're zoomed all the way out expand as you zoom in. In other words You're expanding the area above and below where your image can go. If you adjust the `contentInset` it will bring in that dead area and not allow the scrollview to move the image out of the window.

```swift
public func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
    let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size

    let verticalPadding = imageViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height ? (scrollViewSize.height - imageViewSize.height) / 2 : 0
    let horizontalPadding = imageViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width ? (scrollViewSize.width - imageViewSize.width) / 2 : 0

    if verticalPadding >= 0 {
        // Center the image on screen
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalPadding, left: horizontalPadding, bottom: verticalPadding, right: horizontalPadding)
    } else {
        // Limit the image panning to the screen bounds
        scrollView.contentSize = imageViewSize
    }

}
```

This looks almost the same as an open source Cocoapod I help manage, [SwiftPhotoGallery](https://github.com/Inspirato/SwiftPhotoGallery). Take a look at the code for the [`SwiftPhotoGalleryCell`](https://github.com/Inspirato/SwiftPhotoGallery/blob/develop/Pod/Classes/SwiftPhotoGalleryCell.swift) and you should get a pretty good idea of how to do this. (Feel free to just use the cocoapod too if you want!)

Comment: is it possible for you to combine your code into mine ? i tried adding the code and working to fix it but didn't work. i saw the sample but its using constraints, is there is any possible way without the constraints ?